# how to use process and setInterval in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, process, setinterval

When I use process and setInterval in react native, code like this:

```
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'pro' : 'test';

// line

import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponet = () => {
  const [countDownTimer, setCountDownTimer] = useState(0);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  // error tips: Argument of type 'Timer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction '
  setCountDownTimer(setInterval(() => {
    if (--startCounter === 0) {
      clearInterval(countDownTimer);
    } else{
      setCounter(startCounter);
    }
  }, 1000));
}

export default Mycomponet;
```

`setCountDownTimer(setInterval(...))`
will get error tips: Argument of type 'Timer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction '

When I use this in react, I can use window.setInterval to resolve this problem, but in react native it not can be worked.

Comment: Only drop process and use `__DEV__`, but `__DEV__` only distinguishes between development and production environments